# Storing lines of a file as an array of structs in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am trying to create an array of structs from a file.

Each line in the file is of the form:

`old_word new_word` 

 and I have managed to store the file's content to into an array however each line is stored as an element in the array but I would like to load each line as a struct such that I get an array of structs.

My Struct is as follows:

```
typedef struct ChangedWord
{
    char *old;
    char *new;
} word_change_t;
```

My Plan is to run through this resulting array and be able to access `for example the old word in the struct`

I have also managed to store the `old_word` and `new_word` as different variables. So I can create an array of only `old` or `new_words` but I cannot for the life of me see how I can store both words as a struct and get an array of structs.

My Code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct ChangedWord
{
    char *old;
    char *new;
} word_change_t;

char **readFile(char *filename, int *len);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  if (argc == 1)
   {
    printf("Usage add file\n");
    return 1;

  }

  int length = 0;
  char **words = loadfile(argv[1],&length);

printf("%d\n", length);

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  printf("%s\n",words[i]);
}

free(words);

  return 0;
}

char **readfile(char *filename, int *len)
{
const int REALLOCSIZE = 100;

  FILE *f = fopen(filename,"r");
  if (!f) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file\n");
    return NULL;
  }
  int arrlen = REALLOCSIZE;
   char **lines = malloc(sizeof(word_change_t) * REALLOCSIZE);
   char buf[1000];
   int i = 0;
   int counter = 2;
   while (fgets(buf,1000,f))
   {
     char old_str[500], new_str[500];

         strcpy(old_str, strtok(buf , " "));
         strcpy(new_str, strtok(NULL, " "));

     if (i == arrlen)
     {
        counter++;
       arrlen += REALLOCSIZE;
       char **newlines = realloc(lines, sizeof(word_change_t) * counter * REALLOCSIZE);
       if(!newlines)
       {
      printf("Out of memory\n");
      //return 2;
       }
       lines = newlines;

     }


    old_str[strlen(old_str)] = '\0';
    new_str[strlen(new_str)-1] = '\0';

    int old_strlen = strlen(old_str);
    int new_strlen = strlen(new_str);

    char *str_old = malloc((old_strelen + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(str_old, old_str);

    char *str_new = malloc((new_strlen + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(str_new, new_str);

word_change_t.old = *str_old;
word_change_t.old = *str_new;
//DEBUG Start
printf("%s\n",word_pair_t.old);

//printf("%lu\n",strlen(new_str));
// DEBUG End    

lines[i] = word_change_t;
    i++;
   }
   *len = i;

   return lines;

}
```

WhI get the erroren I run it `error: expected identifier or '('
word_pair_t.old = *str_old;`

How Do I store the elements into an array of structs

Your Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: word_change_t is a type, not an instance of a struct that you can reference. Try simple operations first. create an instance of your struct and fill it manually.

Comment: `char **lines = malloc(REALLOCSIZE * sizeof *lines);` to allocate pointers to struct. Now for each pointer you will need to allocate storage for both `old_word` and `new_word` as each are added to your struct. You will need to keep a counter of `pointers_filled` and when `pointers_filled == pointers_allocated` you will need to `realloc (lines, ..` before you can add additional structs.

Comment: You also never call `readfile` from your `main`, you call some phantom `loadfile`. So, how about the *real* code. I'm all-but-certain you're trying to [do this](https://pastebin.com/mhutKEfv), but that's a sheer guess, as there are so very many things wrong with your posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually quite a bit more confused about how to approach the problem than originally thought. Since you have declared your struct containing two pointers, and you want to capture both `old` and `new` words in the `struct`, you do not want `words` or `lines` to be *pointer-to-pointer-to* `char`, instead you want both to simply be a *pointer-to* `word_change_t`. That way you can allocate a block of memory for structures and then allocate an `old` and `new` and store the old and new word pairs in each struct. You can then `realloc` your block of structures when you need more.

While you are free to pass a filename as a parameter and open the file in your function -- you generally open and validate the file being open in the caller, and then pass the open `FILE*` pointer as a parameter to the function. If the file open fails, there is no need to make the function call to begin with.

Let's start with updating your function declaration to take an open `FILE*` to read pairs of words from and change the type for the pointer that will hold the number of struct allocated on return to `size_t` instead of `int` (you can't have a negative count of struct). Let's also update the return type to return a pointer to the allocated block of struct, e.g.

```
word_change_t *readfile (FILE *fp, size_t *n);
```

Now in `main()` you can validate the filename is given as an argument (or read from `stdin` by default if no filename is given) and then make your call to `readfile`, e.g.

```
#define REALLOCSIZE    2    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC        1024
...
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    size_t length = 0;              /* number of structs */
    word_change_t *words = NULL;    /* pointer to struct */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    words = readfile (fp, &length); /* read all pairs of words into words */
```

Now in `readfile()`, you allocate an initial number of struct (2 based on `REALLOCSIZE` above and begin reading lines. Remember for every allocation or reallocation, you must validate that it succeeds before using the memory.

```
word_change_t *readfile (FILE *fp, size_t *n)
{
    size_t  allocated = REALLOCSIZE,    /* initial no. of structs */
            used = 0;                   /* counter tracking no. used */
    char buf[MAXC];                     /* buf to hold line */
    /* allocate initial struct */
    word_change_t *lines = malloc (allocated * sizeof *lines);

    if (!lines) {   /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-lines");
        return NULL;
    }
    ...
```

Now you will begin reading each line containing your pair of words from your file. The first thing after declaring any local variables you need it to check if reallocation is needed by checking if `used == allocated` (`used` being the counter tracking the number of struct filled, and `allocated` being the number of struct allocated). **Note** for `realloc` you always use a *temporary* pointer to prevent losing the pointer to your original block of memory a creating a memory-leak if `realloc` fails returning `NULL`.

```
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line */
        size_t oldlen, newlen;          /* old/new string lengths */

        if (used == allocated) {        /* check if realloc needed */
            /* always realloc using a temporary pointer */
            void *tmp = realloc (lines, 2 * allocated * sizeof *lines);
            if (!tmp) {                 /* validate reallocation */
                perror ("realloc-lines");
                if (used) {         /* if pairs stored */
                    *n = used;      /* set no. stored */
                    return lines;   /* return pointer to struct */
                }
                free (lines);       /* none stored - free structs */
                return NULL;        /* return NULL */
            }
            lines = tmp;        /* assign realloc'ed block to lines */
            allocated *= 2;     /* update no. allocated */
        }
        ...
```

You are now guaranteed to have a struct allocated providing your two character pointers `old` and `new` for which you can allocate storage for each word and then assign the starting address to `old` or `new` as required. You can use `strtok` if you like, but if you are just dealing with words separated by a space, you can either use `strchr` or `strcspn` to locate the space and get the number of characters. For the second word `new` both are capable of locating the `'\n'` as well allowing you to trim that from the end. For example, you could do something like:

```
        oldlen = strcspn (buf, " ");    /* get no. chars to first space */
        if (!(lines[used].old = malloc (oldlen + 1))) { /* alloc storage */
            perror ("malloc-oldstr");
            break;
        }
        memcpy (lines[used].old, buf, oldlen);  /* copy from buf to old */
        lines[used].old[oldlen] = 0;            /* nul-terminate */

        oldlen++;   /* increment past space in buf */
        newlen = strcspn (buf + oldlen, "\n");  /* get no. of chars to \n */
        if (!(lines[used].new = malloc (newlen + 1))) { /* alloc storage */
            perror ("malloc-oldstr");
            break;
        }
        memcpy (lines[used].new, buf + oldlen, newlen); /* copy buf to new */
        lines[used].new[newlen] = 0;                    /* nul-terminate */

        used++;     /* increment used struct counter */
    }
    ...
```

That's it. Updating the `used` counter at the end completes your read loop. Now before return, you simply need to update the pointer with the used count and return `lines`, e.g.

```
    *n = used;      /* update pointer with no. used before return */

    return lines;   /* return pointer to structs containing pairs */
}
```

Putting it altogether you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define REALLOCSIZE    2    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC        1024

typedef struct ChangedWord {
    char *old;
    char *new;
} word_change_t;

word_change_t *readfile (FILE *fp, size_t *n);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    size_t length = 0;              /* number of structs */
    word_change_t *words = NULL;    /* pointer to struct */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    words = readfile (fp, &length); /* read all pairs of words into words */
    if (!words) {
        fputs ("error: readFile() failed.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    printf ("\n%zu words_chang_t:\n\n", length);    /* number of structs */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {           /* loop over each */
        printf ("words[%2zu] : %s  %s\n",           /* output word pair */
                i, words[i].old, words[i].new);
        free (words[i].old);    /* free old */
        free (words[i].new);    /* free nwe */
    }
    free (words);               /* free pointers */

    return 0;
}

word_change_t *readfile (FILE *fp, size_t *n)
{
    size_t  allocated = REALLOCSIZE,    /* initial no. of structs */
            used = 0;                   /* counter tracking no. used */
    char buf[MAXC];                     /* buf to hold line */
    /* allocate initial struct */
    word_change_t *lines = malloc (allocated * sizeof *lines);

    if (!lines) {   /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-lines");
        return NULL;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line */
        size_t oldlen, newlen;          /* old/new string lengths */

        if (used == allocated) {        /* check if realloc needed */
            /* always realloc using a temporary pointer */
            void *tmp = realloc (lines, 2 * allocated * sizeof *lines);
            if (!tmp) {                 /* validate reallocation */
                perror ("realloc-lines");
                if (used) {         /* if pairs stored */
                    *n = used;      /* set no. stored */
                    return lines;   /* return pointer to struct */
                }
                free (lines);       /* none stored - free structs */
                return NULL;        /* return NULL */
            }
            lines = tmp;        /* assign realloc'ed block to lines */
            allocated *= 2;     /* update no. allocated */
        }

        oldlen = strcspn (buf, " ");    /* get no. chars to first space */
        if (!(lines[used].old = malloc (oldlen + 1))) { /* alloc storage */
            perror ("malloc-oldstr");
            break;
        }
        memcpy (lines[used].old, buf, oldlen);  /* copy from buf to old */
        lines[used].old[oldlen] = 0;            /* nul-terminate */

        oldlen++;   /* increment past space in buf */
        newlen = strcspn (buf + oldlen, "\n");  /* get no. of chars to \n */
        if (!(lines[used].new = malloc (newlen + 1))) { /* alloc storage */
            perror ("malloc-oldstr");
            break;
        }
        memcpy (lines[used].new, buf + oldlen, newlen); /* copy buf to new */
        lines[used].new[newlen] = 0;                    /* nul-terminate */

        used++;     /* increment used struct counter */
    }
    *n = used;      /* update pointer with no. used before return */

    return lines;   /* return pointer to structs containing pairs */
}
```

Without having an inputfile from you to test against, I just created a 2 column file of words from `/var/lib/dict/words` where each word was separated from the first by a space. Testing provides:

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/words_old_new dat/words2col.txt

50 words_chang_t:

words[ 0] : bobbysock  Bakersville
words[ 1] : ailourophobes  Basil
words[ 2] : Baathism  begrim
words[ 3] : arachnid  archiepiscopacy
words[ 4] : backbencher  allowance
words[ 5] : babyproofs  binocles
words[ 6] : bookplate  animalcula
words[ 7] : aphetizes  brecciating
words[ 8] : Aeginetans  backpacking
words[ 9] : befortune  besnows
<snip>
words[48] : besottedly  bear
words[49] : antiderivative  Alleghenies
```

(38 words were snipped for brevity of output)

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/words_old_new dat/words2col.txt
==26460== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==26460== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==26460== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==26460== Command: ./bin/words_old_new dat/words2col.txt
==26460==

50 words_chang_t:

words[ 0] : bobbysock  Bakersville
words[ 1] : ailourophobes  Basil
words[ 2] : Baathism  begrim
words[ 3] : arachnid  archiepiscopacy
words[ 4] : backbencher  allowance
words[ 5] : babyproofs  binocles
words[ 6] : bookplate  animalcula
words[ 7] : aphetizes  brecciating
words[ 8] : Aeginetans  backpacking
words[ 9] : befortune  besnows
<snip>
words[48] : besottedly  bear
words[49] : antiderivative  Alleghenies
==26460==
==26460== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26460==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26460==   total heap usage: 109 allocs, 109 frees, 8,687 bytes allocated
==26460==
==26460== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==26460==
==26460== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==26460== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code, for example that you have written `old_strelen` instead of `old_strlen`. But the error with `expected identifier or '('` is because `word_change_t` is a data type and not a variable.